# R facet with geom_col?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-bar, geom-col

I have imported the below excel file into the RStudio
[image]

My goal is to display in a facet of 4 different barplots with x axis representing the categorical variable of algorithms, and y displays the percentages each time as they are counted already in columns Question_1,2,3,4.
I use this simple R code to plot just one barplot

```
ggplot(data = R_Analysis_draft, mapping = aes(x = algorithms,y = Question_1)) +
     geom_col()
```

How can I display all 4 in the same facet since they all have the same categorical variable `algorithms` putting a header on top of each one different Question and using the percentages?

Comment: Provide the data in `dput()` format, visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-algorithms) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = algorithms, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]
or

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-algorithms) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = algorithms, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

For faceted plotting use

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-algorithms) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = algorithms, y = value)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) + 
  facet_wrap(name~.)
```

[image]
Data

```
df = structure(list(algorithms = c("Alg_1", "Alg_2", "Alg_3", "Alg_4", 
"Alg_5"), Question_1 = c(51L, 43L, 48L, 48L, 54L), Question_2 = c(49L, 
35L, 53L, 39L, 63L), Question_3 = c(55L, 42L, 54L, 48L, 47L), 
    Question_4 = c(52L, 36L, 46L, 48L, 55L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thank you,  that seems like a solution indeed, but what if I need them to be displayed separately as barplots in a facet as I wrote?Isn't this possible?

Comment: Thank you so much @Bappa Das, May I ask can is it possible to put in a facet also pie charts?

Comment: You can ask a new question and also provide your expected output there.

Comment: Actually, I turned out with 6 graphs, which I need to plot in 3 different lines, how can I achieve this @Bappa Das?

Comment: Ok found it added `nrow = 3` within `facet_wrap`